# GAE Map JSON Object from Request to Bean

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, gson

I'm working on GoogleAppEngine for building a RESTful web service.
All is fine but my simple method that accept a simple bean:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "echo")
public String echo(Update message) {
    log.info("The message is: " + message.toString());
    return "done";
}
```

The request is this:

```
{"id":123, "first_name":"hello", "user_name": "world"}
```

The bean is like that:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
public class Update {

    private Integer id;

    private String firstName; 

    private String userName;

    // getter/setter
}
```

But, because the key of the json (`first_name`) is different from java bean (`firstName`) i recive in the echo method's only the id!

I've tried adding `@SerializedName("user_name")` and `@JsonProperty("user_name")` before the variable but nothing..
I can't change the JSON in request, and i wouldn't like to rename the bean's fields.

Any suggestions?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found.

Using:

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
```

cause the malfunction

I change it to:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
```

and now it works

[this post give me the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552590/appengine-endpoints-jsonmappingexception-avoid-field-to-be-serialized)